# How to limit input values ​to one decimal place?

Tags: python

I'm trying to limit input values ​​to one decimal place. If the user inputs more than one decimal places in the input value, output an error sentence in the program.

Without using a rounding function, I want my program to only work with 1st decimal places and integers.

Comment: If `x` is a float variable, `assert (x * 10) % 1 == 0` would raise an error if `x` has a non-negligible value on the second or higher decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
value = float(input("Input your number: "))
if (value * 10) % 1 == 0:
    print(value)
else:
    print("Only enter up to 1 decimal point")
```

Essentially we are checking if the value entered (times 10 to get a whole number) has a remainder. If there's no remainder, we are just printing the value, otherwise, an error message pops up.

Output:

```
Input your number: 1.2
>>> 1.2
```

```
Input your number: 6.42
>>> Only enter up to 1 decimal point
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check if the input is convertible to `float`, then validate the decimal place.

```py
def decimal():
    try:
        number = float(input("Type in your number: "))
        
        if number not in [round(number, i) for i in [0, 1]]:
            print("Your number should have less than one decimal place.")
        else:
            print("No errors were detected.")
            return number
    except ValueError:
        print("Your input is not convertible to type float.")
```

---

### Results

Let's try a few test cases on the `decimal` function.

```
Type in your number: 5.98
ValueError: Your number should have less than one decimal place.
```

```
Type in your number: 10.7
No errors were detected.
```

It also works with negative values.

```
Type in your number: -8
No errors were detected.
```

Input of type `str` is not convertible to type `float`.

```
Type in your number: Python
ValueError: Your input is not convertible to type float.
```

Comment: Great answer, but he said wants it "without using a rounding function".

Comment: @krmogi By "without using a rounding function", I think the author meant to say that he/she wanted to *restrict* the input to one decimal place instead of *rounding*, for example, `8.91436` to `8.9`. There is no limitation to the `round` function as it is a built-in function and this is not a challenge question.

Answer (score 0):

We need to take the input from user say n. If it has one decimal place, then `n*10` should be `int`, else it has more than 1 decimal places. My code:

```
n=float(input ("Enter n= "))
if n*10==int(n*10):
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Invalid input")
```